# Prevent enter from entering textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, enter, stoppropagation

> I want to allow the user to press <kbd>enter</kbd> and save the text
>   of the textarea, but I want the newline NOT to get applied in the text
>   of the textarea. Is that possible?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/b26mzrxd/1/).

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

just seems to be not enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'we missed `return false;`.

Try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b26mzrxd/2/).

Comment: I can see also that stopPropagation is no longer needed.

Comment: @gsamaras, Depends. If there is another listeners on that `textarea`, they can be fired, if not stop the event propagation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is `e.preventDefault()`. Stop propagation just stops bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: I swapped this function with stopPropagation, but same effect! Maybe I am missing something, can you show what you are saying in my fiddle?

Comment: well your fiddle has a syntax error, so if you are testing it there, that is the problem

Comment: Open up your dev tools `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Um, no. Look at the console

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code here in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/fzjd9q7L/) and it works fine for me

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 10 || event.keyCode == 13) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: @gsamaras this one should work [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/g2zjvown/])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#cagetextbox').keypress(function(e){return CancelNewLine(e);});

function CancelNewLine(e)
{
    var keynum;
    if(window.event) // IE
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        keynum = e.which; 

    return (keynum != 13);
}
```